# Using Regex to capture the first character of a string while ignoring "the " and "a "

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of objects that are music artists in Javascript.  I'm trying to construct a regex to select the artists that begin with a selected letter.  However, I need to exclude "the " and "a " in each artist name string while still considering the beginning character for the remainder of the string.

So far this is as close as I get:

```
/(?!^the |^a )\b${indexCharacter}?/i
```

I have not implemented ${indexCharacter} yet, was just focusing on using ^r in its place with a test case of "The Rolling Stones" to test it out.

So that worked and I thought I'd test it out on the string "The Mighty Mighty Bostones" and It grabs the 1st and 2nd "M".  I'm close, I just can't figure out how to make it stop at the first instance.  I thought the question mark would do it.

There's definitely a way to do this.  Help please?

Comment: I think we need to see some sentences here, as well as the logic for how to know when a name ends.

Comment: The first letter will be stored in Group 1 of regex - [`^(?:a|the)?\s*(\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/2jtlZB/1)

Comment: ^^ I second that. I'm a bit confused too. Do you want to select the artist or just th letter. Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/OdE94d/1). Is that what you are after?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, I want to filter "the " and "a " and then select the whole name including "the " and "a " for display.  This is intended to work similiar to an address book alphabet index.  I want to display only the artist names that start with a "J", for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a test case based on your description:

```js
const artists = [
  { name: 'The Rolling Stones', stars: 5 },
  { name: 'Santana', stars: 5 },
  { name: 'Queen', stars: 4 },
  { name: 'The Beatles', stars: 3 },
  { name: 'Jimi Hendrix', stars: 5 },
  { name: 'Joe Cocker', stars: 3 },
  { name: 'Pink Floyd', stars: 5 },
  { name: 'Rammstein', stars: 5 },
  { name: 'The Clash', stars: 2 },
  { name: 'The Cure', stars: 2 },
  { name: 'The Damned', stars: 3 },
  { name: 'Tool', stars: 2 },
  { name: 'A Perfect Circle', stars: 1 },
  { name: 'Alice Cooper', stars: 4 },
];

function findArtists(query) {
  return artists.filter(a => {
    let re = new RegExp('^' + query.toLowerCase());
    return re.test(a.name.toLowerCase().replace(/^((a|the)\s)/, ''));
  });
}

[ 'a', 'j', 'ji', 'r', 't' ].forEach(query => {
  let result = findArtists(query);
  console.log('- query: ' + query + ' => ' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Output:

```
- query: a => [{"name":"Alice Cooper","stars":4}]
- query: j => [{"name":"Jimi Hendrix","stars":5},{"name":"Joe Cocker","stars":3}]
- query: ji => [{"name":"Jimi Hendrix","stars":5}]
- query: r => [{"name":"The Rolling Stones","stars":5},{"name":"Rammstein","stars":5}]
- query: t => [{"name":"Tool","stars":2}]
```

Explanation of regex `new RegExp('^((a|the)\\s)?' + query.toLowerCase())`

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start group 1 (you could turn that into a non-capturing `(?:...)` group)

  - `(a|the)` - group for `a` or `the`
  - `\\s` - followed by space (double backslash due to string)
- `)?` - end group 1, `?` makes it optional
- followed by the query term, turned lowercase
- tip: escape special regex chars in query if the query is user specified

Comment: Wow!  That's basically everythingt I was trying to accomplish way beyond the regex itself.  One issue, I tried the expression itself with some js regex simulators and I couldn't make it work subbing out "+query.toLowerCase()" with the letter "r".  and adding /i.  But I think that's just me.  I'll put it into the actual code.  Thank you for the meticulous response!  And yes, the user query input is constrained.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  Thank you!

Comment: That worked good, but I found an exception.  In a test case of:"C", I correctly got "Cage The Elephant", "The Clash", and "The Cure".  However, if I click on "T", I get "The Clash", The Cure", "The Damned" and "Tool".

Comment: Same with "A", it included "A Perfect Circle"

Comment: I added the new test cases, and tweak the code; easy fix

Comment: Yep!  Firing on all cylinders now!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a complex regex here, you can just remove the prefixes you don't want and then get the first letter:

```js
function getArtistFirstLetter(artist) {
  return artist
    .replace(new RegExp('/the |a /i'), '')
    .charAt(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

although you will have a whitespace on ahead this will work

```
/(?=[^a|the]).+/i
```

actually there's no need to use question mark

```
/[^a|the].+/i
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `[^a|the]` is a character class that means any single character that is not  `a`, `e`, `h`, `t`, or `|`.